# Should Azure CDN typically be used for serving images (other than static layout elements)?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

So, in a scenario where we have web site/app that has some static images (layout parts, icons, etc...) and some images within the actual content (user posts containing images, e.g.) - is it usual/preferable to use CDN in both cases or is it more common to use CDN for static content and without CDN (blob storage directly) for content images?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515651/best-performance-for-storing-static-files-images-css-javascript-cdn-blob/9518657#9518657) about this, and the following is the related info:

You can go with CDN if you want, but it's best to use CDN for infrequently-changing content (as you can't forcibly expire the content). So, if you have some CSS, background images, etc. that don't change too often, those are great CDN candidates. If it's a daily-changing front-page HTML file, I would skip CDN on that one.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am sorry, of course its helpful. I was waiting if someone else would add another answer and forgot about it in the meantime. My bad, sorry. Could you just add a sentence of your opinion about the case where its not daily-changing html but for example an image (content image, not backgrounds) within a news article, e.g.? Would you use CDN or storage directly?